# Input props not working on pure function component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I have the following:

```
const actionCreators = {
    action: AppReducer.actionCreators.action
}
interface GlobalState {
    user: Model.User | null;
}

interface InputState {
    setStashBarWidth(width: number);
    stashWidth: number;
}


const Header = (props: (GlobalState & InputState & typeof actionCreators)) => { ... }

const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState): GlobalState => {
    return {
        user: state.app.user
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actionCreators)(Header);
```

My intention is to make 'InputState' props which can be passed into header, like:

`<Header setStashBarWidth={(number)=>{}} stashWidth={3} />`

However it appears the input props are not being recognized, I can't pass anything to setStashBarWidth or stashWidth as they're not recognized:

> (40,19): Property 'stashBarWidth' does not exist on type
>   'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes> & Readonly<{ c...'.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined the props on your pure component, you've merely asserted the props it will receive in the argument (not the same thing). It's like if you made a regular React component but instead of passing the props in to the generic like so `class X extends React.Component<MyProps>` you instead did `const props: MyProps = this.props;` in your render method.

Try this:

```
const Header: React.SFC<GlobalState & InputState & typeof actionCreators> = (props) => { ... }
```